# How to ask about the last night sleeping, out of the following options - idiomatically?

Tags: idiomatic-language

In case of a couple lovers that slept together at night. Which phrase is more **idiomatic** to ask each other at the morning while waking up?

> Good morning honey:) How was your sleep (at night)? (sleep as a noun)

or

> Good morning honey:)  How did you sleep (at night)? (sleep as verb)

or

> Good morning honey:) How have you been sleeping (at night)?

or

> Good morning honey:) How have you slept (at night)?

Comment: If the options belong to an exam or test question, you should say so. It would also help if you provided any additional dialogue that is included, for instance the response.

Comment: It's my own question,  I'll add an example of dialogue.

Answer (score 3):

The most common way to ask someone how they slept is the following

> Did you sleep well?

A lover might also tag the following effusion  "darling", "my love", "my sweet", "honey" etc.

From the [ThoughtCo](https://www.thoughtco.com/going-to-bed-getting-up-1212037) website here are other ways of greeting someone when you wake up in the morning

> Good morning
>   I hope you had a good night's sleep.
>   I hope you got some good rest.
>   **Did you sleep well?**
>   Did you get a good night's sleep?
>   I slept well, how about you?
>   How did you sleep?
>    Rise and shine.

One of the  OP's suggestions “How did you sleep?” is also listed.